# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Detect Whether Current Page Was Redirected To in a Post Redirect Get Workflow

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

In my C# .NET 4 MVC 3 application I have a delete controller for a set of CRUD pages which uses the *Post Redirect Get* pattern to redirect to an Index controller after a successful delete. I would like to render a button on the Index page only if this page was NOT redirected to by such an action. Is there a simple way to detect if the current page was redirected to (i.e. was reached as the result of a PRG redirect)?

After reading http://blog.simonlovely.com/archive/2008/11/26/post-redirect-get-pattern-in-mvc.aspx my current approach is to set this in my delete controller with `TempData` after the `DeleteMyEntity` method has succeeded:

```
try {
    MyService.DeleteMyEntity(MyViewModel.MyEntity);
    TempData["Redirected"] = true;
    args = new RouteValueDictionary(new { Foo = 1, Baa = 2 });
    return RedirectToAction("Index", args);
} catch (Exception e)
{
   //Logging etc. - redirect should never be reached on exception (and TempData item not set)
   throw(e);
}
```

then in my Index controller I check to see if this value exists and is true:

```
if (TempData["Redirected"] != null)
{
    //we can then do something useful with this
}
```

Another opportunity I see would be to add another item to `args` and check for this in the controller, but in this case I may as well just use `TempData`. Is there a way to do this using a HTTP Response code on the request without needing to pass this data through with `TempData` or a similar mechanism?

Comment: You could read the value of the `referer` header out of `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers`, but it depends on the client side browser behaving nicely. `TempData` is basically designed for this sort of thing and sounds like your best bet.

Comment: sargant I should have pretty good control over the environment. I had a look at this and I can't think of an implementation where I won't need to check if a referer is in a list of referers that I don't want to render the button for. I think it's easier just to pass the flag from the controller I'm redirecting from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use TempData in a similar fashion - for instance, to show a status message (after redirecting to) my view when a record has been added / updated / deleted. This is the kind of simple, throw-away stuff that TempData is used for, so I say what you have is appropriate.

Personally I wouldn't mess with HTTP status codes unless I had an absolute need for it. And you could probably do something with the referrer http header, but again, that would be much messier and more complicated than just using TempData. You have a clean, simple solution that works, I say go with what you have.

Comment: Thank you hawkke. My only concern is that other programmers/my future self working on the project must then be aware of the convention, and it is not bound by something like a ViewModel which is going to give provide a reasonably concrete usage/intellisense hint for this. BUT it may be the best solution in the end since I have a lot of control over it.

Comment: I avoid TempData because it requires the user to assume that the client browser will always make a subsequent request. This violates the "never trust the client" rule.

Comment: @AaronNewton True, you do have to be aware of the convention; but then again, you have to be aware of a lot of conventions because MVC is highly based on patterns and conventions (for instance, the entire PRG pattern you are working on). As far as I'm aware, this is a fairly common way of accomplishing this, so it's just one more convention to keep in the toolbox :)

Comment: @AaronNewton you could wrap the functionality in a filter attribute to make it a little more self-documenting.

Comment: Thank you qes. I have just found out that you can override the controller from a base class with a method signature like so `protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)`. I can then set a property against the controller in this base class (e.g. `bool Redirected`) and throw an exception in `OnActionExecuted` if the value isn't set in the controller in the inheriting class (e.g. set in the method `Delete` or for the whole controller class). Then use this value to modify a property in the ViewModel, assuming that the ViewModels also inherit a base class.

Comment: See http://forums.asp.net/post/2444434.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuted(v=vs.98).aspx. I will try and post a snippet if I get this working.

Answer (score 5):

another route would be to set up a global actionfilter that "injects" that flag for you...

```
public class RedirectDetect: ActionFilterAttribute{
   public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext){
        if (filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult ||
            filterContext.Result is RedirectResult)
        {
             TempData["Redirected"] = true;
             //or what ever other indicator you want to set
        }
   }
}
```

And then you can just call redirectToAction("Index") and then check in your receiving handler

sidenote: I challenge you to say RedirectDetect aloud and not smirk.

Comment: This is what I did to work alongside the cookie temp data provider since it would clear out the cookie on redirects, effectively making my use case useless (PRG messaging). In the provider, I check the flag and then remove it while preventing a save if that's the only flag.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any simpler mechanism and have been using TempData for quite some time to implement Post-Redirect-Get features. As far as I know, this is specifically one of the reasons for TempData's existence. I would continue using it.

Comment: Thank you qes. Another consideration here is if it works, use it :D

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to tell the difference between requests as a result of a 3xx redirection or a straightforward user-initiated GET. The best way is to provide a querystring argument that is only appended by the redirection for the initial POST request, but there is nothing stopping the user from reloading the page with the same querystring.

Hmmm, or you could send a cookie with the redirection from the POST, then remove the cookie in the response of the subsequent GET, like so:

```
public ActionResult PostHandler(ViewModel model) {
    SetCookie("redirected", "true"); // psuedocode
    return Redirect("GetHandler2");
}

public ActionResult GetHandler2() {
    if( GetCookie("redirected") == "true" ) {
        // do something
    }
    DeleteCookie("redirected");
}
```

Comment: Dai, I will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of George's answer:

```
public class MarkRedirects : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
   {
        if (context.Result is RedirectToActionResult ||
            context.Result is RedirectResult)
        {
            // Obtain and verify the underlying IController
            var controller = context.Controller as Controller;
            if (controller != null)
                controller.TempData["Redirected"] = true; // or set other dictionary data here
        }
   }
}
```

The conditional checks of context.Result can vary based on what method you used to redirect, for instance if you redirected the user via the RedirectToAction() method, `context.Result is RedirectToActionResult` will return true but `context.Result is RedirectToRouteResult` will not.

Because of this, you will want to change up that conditional based on your personal taste of how you redirect users. The current code would work for OP's situation.

If you're going to be using this everywhere, it may be wise to modify a base controller.